# How to create my own proxy for EJB stubs on AS level

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, stub

Is there a way how I can create my own proxy for remote EJB stubs? On application server level?

I was researching the ORB related configuration, such is the property *javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass*, but application servers do not implement it correctly (e.g. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YOKO-429). And it is only related to CORBA, which I understood is only one of possible implementations.

EDIT: the point of doing it at application server level is that I cannot modify application source code, all I get is EAR:

Comment: Do you want to create a client stub to remotely invoke an EJB deployed on an AS or do you want to create an own proxy on server side?

Comment: I want to change behavior of remote EJBs - so they can be used without server side, be mocked, etc. I was thinking I can replace the original  remote stub (already a proxy) by some additional proxy on top of it so I can switch between normal behavior and mocked.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible that easy, without completely fullfill the ejb specification because your proxy has to implement the RMI IIOP protocol in order to make a remote communication possible.

The communication with an EJB from a programming language other than java is not possible. In this case your Application Server has to provide an WebService Interface of your EJB remote interface where the communication is based on xml and the HTTP protocol. 
Have a look at WSDL and Rest. 
I would not recommend to use CORBA because this technology is not supported anymore.

EDIT due to COMMENT

An EJB must be deployed within an appropriate EJB Container, because the whole lifecycle is managed by the container. You may have a look at [EJB embeddable api](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2424/gjlde.html). 
If you don't want to use an Application Server then you can fallback to the base 
RMI technology, which you already mentioned. RMI needs no Application Server but there are some other issues (RMI Registry) which must be considered.

However I would suggest to decouple the logic from your ejb classes and use POJO's for your logic. The EJB itself just delegates the remote method invocations to you POJO's by referencing the appropriate class.
Now you are able to package the logic without any technology dependencies within a jar which can be referenced by any other application.

Have a look at Facade, Strategy or Business Delegate pattern.